# How to pass kwargs from save to post_save signal

Tags: python, django

I'm wiring up a custom post_save signal and noticed that I can't seem to find an easy way to pass a set of kwargs.

During the save itself (inside a custom form)

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(CustomFormThing, self).save(commit=False)
    #set some other attrs on user here ...
    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

Then inside my custom post_save hook I have the following (but never get any kwargs)

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    some_id = kwargs.get('some', None)
    other_id = kwargs.get('other', None)

    if created:
        #do something with the kwargs above...
```

How might I pass kwargs from the save to the post_save event?

Comment: I'm interested in passing other args (non user attributes) that would live on a user profile (isolated from the django user itself). The post save seemed like a great place to accomplish this ... except I can't get at any external variables. I'll try your suggestion and post back if that works (although I'd like to take advantage of the **kwargs on the post_save signal itself)

Comment: I don't think signal is a good idea here. Signals are good when an objects are created in different parts of code (may even outside the app). But in your case the signal is useless if you the object is created outside the form. So I think the most rational way is to create `User` and profile directly in form's save. Easy to implement, easy to understand the code later.

Comment: I believe most people (ok, maybe just me :) do the UserProfile creation and fussing in the overridden save() method, not in post_save(). But your requirements may be different. At any rate, you could also call `instance.get_profile()` in post_save, too, if the profile was already created, and if that would help.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a hard-coded (like) update / create profile in the form save event (overridden or not) as I wanted this to exist in 1 place (and have that place be unaware of the origin save invocation). But as the kwargs here seem to be out of my control maybe it's time to invest in a custom signal ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Built-in signals are sent by Django, so you can't control their kwargs.

You can:

1. Define and send your own signals.
2. Store additional info in model instance. Like this

   ```
   def save(self, commit=True):
       user = super(CustomFormThing, self).save(commit=False)
       #set some other attrs on user here ...
       user._some = 'some'
       user._other = 'other'
       if commit:
           user.save()

       return user

   @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
   def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       some_id = getattr(instance, '_some', None)
       other_id = getattr(instance, '_other', None)

       if created:
           #do something with the kwargs above...
   ```

Comment: +1 better answer than mine. I should have thought of using getattr(). Also nice to confirm that you can pass additional attributes using `instance`.

Comment: What about calling `self.save_m2m()` after `user.save()`? Isn't that needed?

Comment: This is exactly what is needed! By overwriting the save method in the form and by setting the extra attribute will be enough to read that value in the post_save signal. In my case, I needed to see if some data changed so by setting the initial data from the instance in the form __init__ function and then setting this value in the save method, I was able to compare the before and after IN THE POST SAVE SIGNAL!! without having to set "update_fields" when calling the save method

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to pass a separate set of kwargs. What args do you want in addition to the `User` attributes? You can access the `User` attributes in the signal handler on the `instance` argument. `instance` will be the `User` object that just got saved.

If there are other things you want to pass along, I suppose you could try to use the `instance` arg as a carrier pigeon:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(CustomFormThing, self).save(commit=False)
    user.foo = 'bar'
    if commit:
        user.save()
    ...
```

Then in the handler:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    myfoo = instance.foo
```

But the above is untested, and I'm not sure it will even work.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass additional arguments as below:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(CustomFormThing, self).save(commit=False)
    #set some other attrs on user here ...
    if commit:
        user.save(signal_kwargs={'_some': 'some', '_other': 'other'})

    return user
```

And you can get it from the post save method like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    some_id = kwargs.get('some', None)
    other_id = kwargs.get('other', None)
    if created:
        #do something with the kwargs above...
```

Comment: signal_kwargs does not exist in django source code: <https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adjango%2Fdjango%20signal_kwargs&type=code>. You will get an error : "save() got an unexpected keyword argument".

Comment: But it would be a nice feature request to make: <https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/#requesting-features>