# Adding UserProfile field value when creating User

Tags: python, django

I've gotten this far with UserProfiles on Django 1.4.5. It works, but now I would like to be able to add a value to my custom field in the admin when creating the user. The way this works, I need to create the new user, then go back and add the UserProfile field.

Where and what do I need to do to add the UserProfile field upon User creation?

```
### admin.py
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'


# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

    # Something here?


    # Re-register UserAdmin
    admin.site.unregister(User)
    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)



### models.py
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Create additional fields for users.

    Site ID

    """
    # This field is required
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Additional fields to add.
    site_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Site ID')


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

        # Or maybe here?

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: you have the post_save signal correct. It should create the profile when user object is created. What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: The above creates an empty UserProfile for the newly created user. I want to populate the Site ID during User creation. Trying with the above produces a "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" error. Of course, it's quite possible I'm barking up the wrong tree thinking that Django is my problem.

Comment: You can do `userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance); userprofile.site_id=id; userprofile.save()`

Comment: How do I acquire the number that was entered in the Site ID field on the User form in admin in order to save it to the UserProfile? It is not any sort of generated ID, but a number entered by the creator of the user. http://imgur.com/C1U2HnT

Comment: [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299034/how-to-pass-kwargs-from-save-to-post-save-signal) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was actually running into this issue. This post solved it.

[Django - UserProfile m2m field in admin - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117373/django-userprofile-m2m-field-in-admin-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)